# How do Oracle temporary tables exactly work in a stored procedure like this?

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

Suppose I'm using the following Oracle code in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (
    field1 NUMBER,
    field2 NUMBER
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
```

This particular stored procedure may be called concurrently by different users at any single moment. As I understand it, the data visible to the user in the temporary table will be private to him or her, and these rows are deleted on a COMMIT.

However, how do the following work with respect to this:

1. Is it safe to call the CREATE statement above **every single time** the stored procedure is called? Would this result in an error cause there already "exists" a temporary table (possibly) created by a different user (/session)? Or would this be OK, since the server treats them privately anyway?
2. What exactly happens with the ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS? I assume that this only deletes the rows specific to the particular user session, leaving the data by other sessions unharmed, correct?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local Temporary table in Oracle 10 (for the scope of Stored Procedure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192265/local-temporary-table-in-oracle-10-for-the-scope-of-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q1: Is it safe to call the
>   CREATE statement above every single
>   time the stored procedure is called?

The main reason you create a global temporary table (`GTT`) is to create once (not inside procedure) and use it as private table for a session. It will throw an error if the table already exist.

> Q2: What exactly happens with the ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS?

Yes. The data gets deleted once you commit. This happens only for the session you operate.

Check [creating](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/tables.htm) `GTT` and its [use](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg03sch.htm#ADFNS002).

Comment: so, with respect to its existence, it behaves just like a normal table --- it's the data that's actually temporary. got it. thanks! :)

Comment: That's right. Documentation says "The definition of a temporary table is visible to all sessions, but the data in a temporary table is visible only to the session that inserts the data into the table."

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd just leave the table there.  No sense in dropping and recreating it all the time.  It will cause concurency issues as you say.
2. Yes.