# Create a temp table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, temp-tables

I'm working with an Oracle 10g database, and I want to extract a group of records from one table, and then use that for pulling records out of a bunch of related tables.

If this were T-SQL, I'd do it something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #PatientIDs (
  pId int
)

INSERT INTO #PatientIDs
  select distinct pId from appointments

SELECT * from Person WHERE Person.pId IN (select pId from #PatientIDs)

SELECT * from Allergies WHERE Allergies.pId IN (select pId from #PatientIDs)

DROP TABLE #PatientIDs
```

However, all the helpful pages I look at make this look like a lot more work than it could possibly be, so I think I must be missing something obvious.

(BTW, instead of running this as one script, I'll probably open a session in Oracle SQL Developer, create the temp table, and then run each query off it, exporting them to CSV as I go along. Will that work?)

Comment: Why do you need the temp table step? You're just replacing one select with another. Is the initial select very expensive - Or is it in case a concurrent transaction changes things?

Comment: Oracle is not SQL Server, and the situations where we need to use temporary tables are actually quite uncommon.  Please read my answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192265/local-temporary-table-in-oracle-10-for-the-scope-of-stored-procedure/1193443#1193443

Comment: I was simplifying -- what I was actually trying to do was grab the last 100 patients (minus a bit of duplication). But talking it out below reminded me that I could just grab 100 patients starting at midnight this morning, and not have to worry about SYSDATE changing as I went along. :-)

Comment: There are nothing about date restrictions in question text. Can you please update question with details of selection criterious?

Comment: You might want to look at some of the other, non-default, transaction isolation levels available. I believe serializable and read only both show results as of the beginning of the transaction. Rows inserted after the transaction started would not appear.

Answer (score 12):

Oracle has temporary tables, but they require explicit creation:

```
create global temporary table...
```

The data in a temporary table is private for the session that created it and can be session-specific or transaction-specific.  If data is ***not*** to be deleted until the session ends, you need to use `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` at the end of the create statement.  There's also no rollback or commit support for them...

I see no need for temp tables in the example you gave - it risks that updates made to the `APPOINTMENTS` table since the temp table was populating won't be reflected.  Use IN/EXISTS/JOIN:

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM PERSON p
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM APPOINTMENTS a
                WHERE a.personid = a.id)

SELECT p.* 
  FROM PERSON p
 WHERE p.personid IN (SELECT a.id
                        FROM APPOINTMENTS a)

SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
  FROM PERSON p
  JOIN APPOINTMENTS a ON a.id = p.personid
```

JOINing risks duplicates if there are more than one APPOINTMENT records associated to a single PERSON record, which is why I added the DISTINCT.

Comment: That was the way I was considering doing it at first, but I'm filtering it for apptDate < SYSDATE, so it could change between the first table I extract and the last one. I support I could just do it for apptDate is yesterday, as that would avoid the problem in question... thanks!

Comment: yesterday is `apptdDate >= trunc(sysdate)-1 and apptdDate < trunc(sysdate)`

Answer (score 7):

Oracle doesn't have the facility to casually create temporary tables in the same way as SQL Server.  You have to create the table explicitly in the database schema (`create global tempory table`).  This also means that you need permissions that allow you to create tables, and the script must explicitly be deployed as a database change.  The table is also visible in a global name space.

This is a significant idiomatic difference between Oracle and SQL Server programming.  Idiomatic T-SQL can make extensive use of tempory tables and genuine requirements to write procedural T-SQL code are quite rare, substantially because of this facility.

Idiomatic PL/SQL is much quicker to drop out to procedural code, and you would probably be better off doing this than trying to fake temporary tables.  Note that PL/SQL has performance oriented constructs such as flow control for explicit parallel processing over cursors and nested result sets (cursor expressions); recent versions have a JIT compiler.

You have access to a range of tools to make procedural PL/SQL code run quickly, and this is arguably idiomatic PL/SQL programming.  The underlying paradigm is somewhat different from T-SQL, and the approach to temporary tables is one of the major points where the system architecture and programming idioms differ.

Answer (score 6):

While the exact problem has been solved, if you want to build up some useful skills in this area, I would take a look at PL/SQL Collections, and particularly bulk SQL operations using pl/sql collections (BULK COLLECT / Bulk Binds), the RETURNING clause, and defining collections using %ROWTYPE.

You can dramatically reduce the amount of pl/sql code you write through understanding all the above - although always remember that an all-SQL solution will almost always beat a PL/SQL one.

Comment: would be good to have an example alongside this suggestion