# How to create and use temporary table in oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle

I want to create temporary table in stored procedure and access it in the same but I got error that `ORA-00942:Table or view does not exists.`
Following is the procedure that i tried,

```
Create procedure myproc
  IS
  stmt varchar2(1000);
  BEGIN
  stmt:='CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY table temp(list if columns) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';

  execute immediate stmt;

  insert into temp values('list of column values');

 END;
```

This is the way I used to create temporary table but I got error, is there any other way to perform this task?

Comment: @tbone's answer shows what you should be doing, but to explain what you're seeing: You can't do this because at the time the procedure is compiled `temp` doesn't exist yet. The compiler doesn't attempt to parse the dynamic SQL, not least because it has no idea if it will work at runtime. The only way this approach would work is if the insert was turned into dynamic SQL too; but this is not how temporary tables work in Oracle so don't do it like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local Temporary table in Oracle 10 (for the scope of Stored Procedure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192265/local-temporary-table-in-oracle-10-for-the-scope-of-stored-procedure)

Comment: This issue has been addressed in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747649/exception-ora-08103-object-no-longer-exists-on-using-setfetchsize-of-hibernate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just create it first (once, outside of your procedure), and then use it in your procedure.  You don't want to (try to) create it on every call of the procedure.

```
create global temporary table tmp(x clob)
on commit delete rows;

create or replace procedure...
-- use tmp here
end;
```

Comment: But why? I found it strange. I.E. I need a "virtual" table. Can I create it inside the procedure itself?

Comment: @Gik25 whether you use an actual temp table or use other approaches depends on your specific situation.  Maybe post a new question with your specifics, you'll most likely get some good responses.

Comment: I second @Revious 
I have a need to create, use & destroy temp tables with in a Proc, Oracle is not liking it, any ideas ?

Comment: what if this procedure is defined inside a package?

Comment: This method will not work correctly if you multiple concurrent processes running at the same time that try to use this table, unless you have something that makes it unique between process runs  - otherwise you can pick up junk in a query that does not belong or put data in that messes up another process run. Several database systems allow creating temp tables inside of a procedure such as Select * into #tmp  - table name. These tables will not interfere with other instances of the same procedure.

Answer (score 2):

```
Create or replace procedure myprocedure
is 
   stmt varchar2(1000);
   stmt2 varchar2(1000);
begin
    stmt := 'create global temporary table temp(id number(10))';
    execute immediate stmt;
    stmt2 := 'insert into temp(id) values (10)';
    execute immediate stmt2;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this answer as it was wrong. I am a recent MSSQL convert and because of the way oracle implements global temp tables, if you really DO need to use temp tables, creating them once and leaving them there is the way to go. Unless you use dynamic sql in your procs exclusively (have fun debugging), you will not be able to successfully compile your package unless the tables referenced already exist. Oracle validates any objects referenced in methods that you attempt to compile, which is why you got the 942 error. I love the way Oracle manages scope with these global temp tables. That, alone, sold me on the idea.

Comment: This is generally a really bad practice in Oracle.  Tables do not simply disappear willy-nilly.  Why add extra (slow) code, force dynamic SQL everywhere, and lose all hope of configuration management? Temporary tables are almost never useful anyway.  They can usually be replaced by regular tables, inline views, or a collection.

Comment: Nevermind my answer, I am a recent MSSQL convert. In the last week, I have come to a better understanding of Oracles implementation of temp tables. The more I use Oracle, the more I like it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
Create of replace procedure myprocedure
is 
   stmt varchar2(1000);
   stmt2 varchar2(1000);
begin
    stmt := 'create global temporary table temp(id number(10))';
    execute immediate stmt;
    stmt2 := 'insert into temp(id) values (10)';
    execute immediate stmt2;
end;
```

Comment: That's actually bad advice. Create the temp. tables outside of stuff that insert/updates/delete from them.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc IS
BEGIN

    CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp (id NUMBER(10)) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS AS
        SELECT 10 FROM dual;

END;
/
```

Comment: Please include some explanations along with your code?