# Dynamic Table Creation in Stored Procedure along with insertion

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure which contains dynamic sample table creation, after that I have insert into sample table statement.

When I compile the procedure, it says table or view does not exists. How to handle this scenario? Please give me if any other alternate solution.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local Temporary table in Oracle 10 (for the scope of Stored Procedure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192265/local-temporary-table-in-oracle-10-for-the-scope-of-stored-procedure)

Comment: There is very rarely a need to do this in Oracle.  The possible solutions depend on *exactly* what you want to achieve, so more details of your scenario would be helpful.  However, the thread I linked to above covers most of the ground.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9310860/266304) is also similar to yours and points to the same thread APC linked to above; the comment explains the error you're getting, and it has an answer that shows how to create a GTT if that really is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

is that possible to change your insert statement to 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into sample values(1)';
it will avoid compile issue.