# Create and insert a row into the table in stored procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
create or replace procedure sample
as
ID VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
execute immediate
'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE UPDATE_COLUMN_NO_TP
(
NAME VARCHAR2(256)
)';

INSERT INTO UPDATE_COLUMN_NO_TP
SELECT SRC_PK_COLUMNS.PK_KEY 
  FROM SRC_PK_COLUMNS 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT 1
  FROM TGT_PK_COLUMNS
 WHERE TGT_PK_COLUMNS.ID = SRC_PK_COLUMNS.ID);
END;
```

Error is:

```
The table is no exist.
```

So, I want a best solution for this scenario. In my stored procedure I have 10 temporary tables. All are all dynamic creations and inserts.

Comment: The whole point of global temporary tables is that you don't create them on the fly. You create them once, and use them afterwards whenever you need them. (You _cannot_ "fix" that procedure as it is.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and use temporary table in oracle stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310860/how-to-create-and-use-temporary-table-in-oracle-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

Table `UPDATE_COLUMN_NO_TP` not exists at compile time, so you got the error.
If you created a table dynamically, you should access it dynamically.
And pay attention to Mat's comment about essence of GTT.

---

```
execute immediate '
INSERT INTO UPDATE_COLUMN_NO_TP
SELECT SRC_PK_COLUMNS.PK_KEY 
  FROM SRC_PK_COLUMNS 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1
    FROM TGT_PK_COLUMNS
    WHERE TGT_PK_COLUMNS.ID = SRC_PK_COLUMNS.ID
  )
';
```

Comment: Ok, i got one idea... i will create 10 tables and use them where ever needed and truncate them at the ending... Is it best ?

Comment: But, n number of users will access the stored procedure at a time. For that situation, can we apply above said.

Comment: @user1990383 - GTT has option `on commit delete rows`, so it truncates automatically on commit or rollback.

Comment: @user1990383 - GTT has separate instance for each session, your data inside GTT would be invisible to other users.

Comment: @user1990383 - wrap `insert` statement into `execute immediate`.

Comment: I tried the same thing insert into execute immediate... even though the error remains same... For me, can you do it in your local, because i am new to oracle....

Comment: @user1990383 - Appended to my answer.