# Exception ORA-08103: object no longer exists on using setfetchsize of Hibernate

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, exception

I'm using Hibernate. I need to fetch around 1000000 records and it will cause timeout exception. So I'm using `setfetchsize` for 6000 records, so that it will distribute the operation in multiple transactions each of 6000 records.

It will take around 21 hours to fetch all.

But meanwhile retrieving records if somebody deletes one of the record which was to be fetched then I get `ORA-08103: object no longer exists`.

Now I want to skip that object which is deleted while retrieving. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't know the context of what you are trying to do, but why do you have to use hibernate, and no direct sql or pl/sql calls.  Would be much faster.

Comment: I can not replace Hibernate since it will cost higher time consumption for project.My problem is that on executing executeQuery oracle will throw ORA-08103: object no longer exists exception because somebody has deleted a record which I was fetching using executeQuery. Now I can not stop anybody to delete a row for the time when I'm fetching records so I want some technique which will cause oracle not to throw exception for the deleted record instead It should skip that record and proceed with the next one.

Comment: @Prashant . . . Why are you fetching a million rows into the application?  It seems to me that there is opportunity to do additional processing in the database, saving lots of time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most likely that a cursor is opened based on a global temporary table(GTT), which had been created with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` option. And the cause of the `ORA-08103: object no longer exists` error is `commit` statement that followed right after the `delete` statement. Here is a simple example:

```
 SQL> declare
  2    type t_recs is table of number;
  3    l_cur sys_refcursor;    -- our cursor
  4    l_rec t_recs; 
  5  
  6  begin
  7  
  8    -- populating a global temporary table GTT1 with sample data  
  9    insert into GTT1(col)
 10      select level
 11        from dual
 12     connect by level <= 1000;
 13  
 14   open l_cur         -- open a cursor based on data from GTT1
 15    for select col
 16          from GTT1;
 17  
 18    -- here goes delete statement
 19    -- and
 20    commit;  <-- cause of the error. After committing  all data from GTT1 will be
 21              -- deleted and when we try to fetch from the cursor
 22    loop      -- we'll face the ORA-08103 error
 23      fetch l_cur    -- attempt to fetch data which are long gone.
 24       bulk collect into l_rec;
 25      exit when l_cur%notfound;
 26    end loop;
 27  
 28  end;
 29  /


ORA-08103: object no longer exists
ORA-06512: at line 24
```

Recreation of global temporary table with `on commit preserve rows` clause will allow to safely fetch data from a cursor that is based on that table without being afraid of facing  `ORA-08103:` error.

Comment: Do you think there can be any other explanation? I've started getting this error with large inserts (just a simple `insert.. select`) from a view into a table upon which no deletes occur. It's _possible_ that another process is trying to truncate the table underneath it but the "raw" table should be locked, which would prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Ben if you are truncating a table while an `insert select ` statement in progress, yes you will get the same error simply because `select` statement is a cursor and `truncate` statement, as it is a DDL statement, causes double commit - before truncate and then after.

Comment: Ah, yes of course; thanks Nicholas. I'll have to track down that rogue process then...

Answer (score 1):

After Struggling one week finally I fixed the Issue:

Solution: Most likely that a cursor is opened based on a global temporary table(GTT), which had been created with ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS option. And the cause of the ORA-08103: object no longer exists error is commit statement that followed right after the delete statement. DBA team didn't agree to change the GTT as on commit preserve rows so finally I added code base in Java Service Layer[Implementing the Spring - Programmatic Transaction]

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO {
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
   private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
      this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }
   public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
      this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
   }
   public void create(String name, Integer age, Integer marks, Integer year){
      TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
      TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

      try {
         String SQL1 = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
         jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL1, name, age);

         // Get the latest student id to be used in Marks table
         String SQL2 = "select max(id) from Student";
         int sid = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForInt( SQL2 );

         String SQL3 = "insert into Marks(sid, marks, year) " + "values (?, ?, ?)";
         jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL3, sid, marks, year);

         System.out.println("Created Name = " + name + ", Age = " + age);
         transactionManager.commit(status);
      } 
      catch (DataAccessException e) {
         System.out.println("Error in creating record, rolling back");
         transactionManager.rollback(status);
         throw e;
      }
      return;
   }
   public List<StudentMarks> listStudents() {
      String SQL = "select * from Student, Marks where Student.id=Marks.sid";
      List <StudentMarks> studentMarks = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, 
         new StudentMarksMapper());

      return studentMarks;
   }
}
```