# ora-08103 object no longer exists error on Do While Not MyRs.EOF

Tags: oracle, vba, vb6

Using VB6 and Oracle

Getting Error as

> "`ora-08103 object no longer exists`"

on following line

```
Do While Not MyRs.EOF
```

Code:

```
Dim str3 As String
Dim str 4 As String

mADO_Connection.ConnectionTimeout = 15
mADO_Connection.Open "connection string"

Dim MyCmd As ADODB.Command
Set MyCmd = New ADODB.Command
MyCmd.CommandText = "PROC_GET_EMPLOYEE"
MyCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Dim MyParam As ADODB.Parameter

Set MyParam = New ADODB.Parameter
MyParam.Name = "DATE"
MyParam.Value = "20150531"
MyParam.Size = 8
MyParam.Direction = adParamInput
MyParam.Type = adVarChar

MyCmd.Parameters.Append MyParam

Dim MyRs As ADODB.Recordset
Set MyRs = New ADODB.Recordset

MyCmd.CommandTimeout = 1000
MyCmd.ActiveConnection = mADO_Connection

MyRs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
MyRs.CacheSize = 100
MyRs.Open MyCmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

If MyRs.Fields.Count > 0 Then

str4 = MyRs.Fields.Count
    Do While Not MyRs.EOF

     str4 = MyRs.Fields("acct#").Value


     For x = 0 To MyRs.Fields.Count - 1
     str4 = str4 & MyRs(x) & ","
     Next

     str4 = Left(str4, Len(str4) - 1)
     str4 = str4 & vbCrLf

     str3 = str3 & str4
     str4 = ""

    MyRs.MoveNext
    If MyRs.EOF Then Exit Do
    Loop


MsgBox "Success"

End If


Set fobj = New FileSystemObject
Set mfile = fobj.CreateTextFile("C:\myfile.csv")
Set mfile = fobj.GetFile("C:\myfile.csv")
Set strm = mfile.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting)
strm.Write str4

Set strm = Nothing
Set fobj = Nothing
Set mfile = Nothing

End Sub
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is an Oracle error, with a forward-only Oracle cursor.
2. The problem's root cause has nothing to do with "File writing".
3. Just remove that silly `If MyRs.EOF Then Exit Do`: you've already got that covered with `Do While Not MyRs.EOF`.
4. Don't forget to close the recordset: `MyRS.Close`.

Comment: I modified as per your suggestion, still i am getting a error

Comment: Q: You've removed the line `If MyRs.EOF Then Exit Do`, correct?  Q: You're still getting `ora-08103 object no longer exists`; now on a *different* line that uses MyRS, correct?  Q: Are there any other processes running that might be deleting rows from Oracle at the same time as your programming is running? Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747649/), [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_08103_object_no_longer_exists.htm) or [here](http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-db-l/ora08103-object-no-longer-exists-4818142).  Also try the same query from sqlplus.

Comment: Deleting rows shouldn't cause that error, but performing DDL like a TRUNCATE or a MOVE may.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before you enter the `Do While` loop:-

```
MyRs.MoveFirst
```