# Oracle Sql : Procedure which can create temporary tables inside it

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am new to Oracle Sql and facing an issue :

I want to create a temporary table inside procedure .

LIKE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P
  AS
  BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A(ID int);
  END P;
```

BUT THIS IS GIVING ME AN ERROR

How Can I Create a temporary table inside procedure.

I have seen other answers on stackoverflow but that doesn't answer my question properly
Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-create-and-use-temporary-table-in-oracle-stored-procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310860/how-to-create-and-use-temporary-table-in-oracle-stored-procedure)

Comment: And why would you want to create a temporary table inside a procedure?

Comment: I think what you want is something like placing a `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE A(ID INT) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` outside the procedure instead. It'll be session specific, and cleared at every commit.

Comment: @Nicholas: See I have to create something into the procedure only because i will call a procedure from a tool and that tool will in turn access the data.

Comment: @ManishSharma - And this tool will only ever use one session to connect to the database?  It will only call the procedure once?  You'll never have to support two users?

Comment: @Justin Cave : Hey I will query the database only once per day from tibco tool , so i think that this is should work out.

Comment: @ManishSharma - So then you're just incurring the cost of creating and dropping the table every day?  I don't see why you wouldn't just create the table once just like you would any other table in your system.  You won't have any PL/SQL code that references the table?

Comment: @Justin:See these are the temporary tables but the main table I will make as regular table .

Comment: @ManishSharma - In Oracle, the definition of a temporary table is intended to be permanent.  Only the data in the table is temporary.  It doesn't make sense to create and drop the same table every day whether that table is temporary or permanent.

Comment: @Justin: See I know what are you talking but for me I have to go like if create separate sql for creating these table then I need to ask separately my production team to put it and that will take much time ya but I will take your suggestion will ask my Lead about this , lets see what he says .

Comment: Of course if your procedure fails half way through, then you've just left a table on the system anyway, and the next time the procedure runs it will fail because the table already exists. You'd better also add code to detect whether the table already exists, and not try to create it again if it does. That way if you get permission to create the table permanently you won't have to redeploy your code again either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Dynamic SQL with [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/executeimmediate_statement.htm):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE p
AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A(id NUMBER)...etc';
END p;
```

Edit: Obviously you'll have to ensure your syntax is correct within the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: -1 it's not helpful to help someone shoot themselves in the foot :)

Comment: It is if that's what they really want to do. People ask questions on here for all sorts of reasons I answered the question asked. A downvote is a reflection of your interpretation of their reason behind the question, not of the answer to the actual question asked.

Comment: No, a downvote is related to how helpful the answer is, nothing more or less. There is a judgement call involved - sometimes it's ok to answer literally even if the approach being taken is not quite the best way; but in other cases (like this one) you need to help the OP understand they are on entirely the wrong course. Even if it's to say "here's how you can do this, but you most probably shouldn't because..."

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree, you're still making the ASSUMPTION that the user doesn't know why they are wanting to do what their question asks. It's your assumption that's led to the downvote. The answer is helpful as it answers the question asked. This site is a Q&A after all. If the OP asked for anything further inc further info about the problem to be solved then more would have been proffered, but they didn't. I have to assume the OP is not stupid so I just answer the question asked.

Comment: To clarify Jeffrey, I'm not saying your wrong per se, just that making assumptions about an OP's reasons can sometimes lead to confusion and/or unhelpful answers. Perhaps I could have asked the OP for more info but the question was pretty clear.

Comment: This may help you Ollie: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191205/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-handle-questions-highlighting-an-ineffective-appr

Answer (score 8):

Why do you want to create a temporary table in a stored procedure in the first place?

It is relatively common to create temporary tables in other databases (SQL Server and MySQL, for example).  It is very, very rare to do the same thing in Oracle.  In almost every case where you are tempted to create a temporary table in Oracle, there is a better architectural approach.  There is a thread over on the DBA stack that discusses [alternatives to temporary tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34279/temporary-table-inside-procedure-oracle/34322#34322) and why they are not commonly needed in Oracle.

Programmatically, you can create objects using dynamic SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dont_do_this
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE a( id INTEGER )';
END;
```

If you create a temporary table dynamically, however, every reference to that table will also need to be via dynamic SQL-- you won't be able to write simple `SELECT` statements against the table.  And the definition of a temporary table in Oracle is global so it is visible to every session.  If you have two different sessions both trying to create the same table, the second session will get an error.  If you expect the table to have a different definition in different sessions, you've got even more problems.

Comment: but I am able to access the table by normal select query

Comment: @ManishSharma - If the table exists, you can reference it in PL/SQL directly.  But if it is possible that the table doesn't exist (which it must be if some other procedure is creating it), then you need to use dynamic SQL to reference the table or your PL/SQL block will fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your procedure as:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS

script varchar(4000);

BEGIN

script:= 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE BNMCODIAGNOSTICASSOCIE_TEMP
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
as select ........';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE script;

commit;

END;
```