# Oracle: create table in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure, partition, materialized-views

I need a procedure to refresh a materialized view partition through PEL.

I would like my procedure to:

1. create a table selecting data from just one year (passed as a parameter) of the detail table and aggregate data on this year
2. create the partition of the corresponding year, if it doesn't exist
3. partition exchange the table with the MVIEW partition I want to refresh
4. drop the table used for loading data

But I've read in many posts (e.g. [Oracle Sql : Procedure which can create temporary tables inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902283/oracle-sql-procedure-which-can-create-temporary-tables-inside-it)) it seems it is not recommended to create table in a procedure, so I would ask if someone has a better solution to do this.

Moreover, if it actually is the best solution, is there a workaround if inside the quote of the execute immediate row I need to open quote without closing quote? e.g:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE as select  TRUNC(date, 'MONTH') from dual;'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Creating a temporary table in a stored procedure is fine.

Comment: you should use `''MONTH''` instead of `'MONTH'`