# How to create a temporary table/view inside an Oracle procedure?

Tags: oracle

I am making a new procedure making queries to a huge table.

The structure of my procedure is as follows:

{

open cursor for

QUERY 1

UNION

QUERY 2

UNION

QUERY 3

}

The structure of QUERY 1 is INNER JOIN 2 ([INNER JOIN 1 (TABLE) x (TABLE) ] x TABLE  )

The structure of QUERY 2 is INNER JOIN 3 ([INNER JOIN 1 (TABLE) x (TABLE) ] x TABLE  )

Is there a way to store [INNER JOIN 1 (TABLE) x (TABLE) ] somewhere so that I don't have to do it twice?

EDIT: Forgot to add that I cannot create a table outside of the procedure because multiple instances of this procedure will run in parallel. They will just block each other from running by inserting in the same table. Also, I don't know how many instances will run in parallel so I cannot create as many tables as instances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create and use temporary table in oracle stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310860/how-to-create-and-use-temporary-table-in-oracle-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 5):

Don't create any tables from PL/SQL. It is possible (hint: dynamic SQL), but that's not how Oracle works.

If you need a table, then create it BEFORE running this procedure, either using `CREATE TABLE` (and name all columns you need), or using `CTAS` (Create Table As Select) which would - basically - be your current query.

That table can be "normal" or "global (or private, depending on database version) temporary table" (GTT). If you use a GTT, only you can see data stored within. If it is a "normal" table, everyone sees data so you might need to pay attention to who sees & uses what.

---

Another option is to use the `CTE` (Common Table Expression, a.k.a. the `WITH` factoring clause) which can be used directly in the procedure as

```
with your_view as
  (select ... 
   from table1 join table2 on ...
               join table3 on ...
  )
select whatever
  from some_other_table join your_view
  where ...
union
select whatever_else
  from yet_another_table join your_View
  where ...
```

**[EDIT, after seeing your edit]**

If you don't want to use a CTE for some reason, then a GTT might be your choice. Why? See my 3rd paragraph ("everyone sees only their own data").

Comment: Would using a GTT allow me to run TWO instances of the procedure at the same time without them interfering with each other?

Comment: Suppose there is one GTT and one procedure (that inserts some rows into that GTT) in that schema. Two (or more) users establish connection. Each of them runs its own procedure. GTT is filled with data. Every users sees only its own data.

Comment: With a GTT, every session has it's own "version" of the table, so there is no interaction or blocking between sessions. It seems to me that your situation is the very thing that GTT was designed and intended for.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a Global Temporary table:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables#temporary-tables