# Rename not possible using procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

--Using Sql developer

```
Create or replace procedure rename_table
is
begin
rename emp to emp1;
end;
```

Compiled with error:

Error(7,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "emp" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look here: https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Take a look at how to ask a question.

Comment: Not exactly the same question but is will show you the code to execute DDL in PLSQL.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272904/ddl-statements-in-pl-sql

Comment: There's code and an error. What was not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RENAME](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9021.htm#SQLRF01608) is a SQL DDL command and as such is not natively supported in PL/SQL - instead, you must use dynamic SQL, e.g.

```
procedure rename_table
is
begin
  execute immediate 'rename emp to emp1';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help dude.