# Create temporary TABLE inside a FUNCTION

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, temp-tables

How can I create a temporary table that I can return when the function is called?

Comment: Read up on dynamic SQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#CACDDACH

Comment: @user2001117: see the tags

Comment: Temporary tables in Oracle shouldn't (need to) be created on the fly; they are permanent objects with session-specific data, not something you can pass around or return. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#sthref81) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#sthref179) for more.

Comment: This is a MS T-SQL way of doing things.  Temporary tables in Oracle are different; to understand more, please see my answer to a very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1193443/146325

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this question is without more information. What is the point of this temporary table? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is this a global temporary table or are you trying to create a 'table-like' output where a pipelined function or a ref cursor is what you're trying to get?

Answer (score -1):

See this one:

```
create or replace procedure maketemptab 
    is 
    sqlstmt varchar2(500); 
    begin 
    sqlstmt := 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE(col1 varchar2(10))'; 
    execute immediate sqlstmt; 
    end;
```

Comment: That will not create a temporary table.

Comment: Not only will it not create a table (there's a sybtax error) creating temporary tables this way is idiomatically wrong for Oracle.