# Combining Multiple Statements in a Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I'm new to Oracle, what I'm trying to achieve I could in SQL but I'm having a tough time in doing it in Oracle.

So within a Stored Procedure, I'm trying to truncate a table, then insert values, lastly run a SELECT statement against the table.

Here is what I have but it doesn't work, when I run this script, it runs with no error but it seems it only goes through the first (TRUNCATE) statement and that's it.

I would like it create the Store Procedure (which it does) and then show me the contents of the table from the SELECT statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure MYSTOREDPROCEDURE is
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE MYTABLE';
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
(COL1,
COL2,
COL3)

SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM MYOTHERTABLE;
end ;
/

SELECT * FROM MYTABLE

END MYSTOREDPROCEDURE;
```

Answer (score 2):

For clarification SQL is a language implmemented by many RDBMS including SQL Server, PostgreSQL etc. If you're doing this in Oracle you *are* using SQL. However, most RDBMS have also added a procedural extension to SQL such as T-SQL (SQL Server), pgPL/SQL (PostgreSQL) and PL/SQL (Oracle). In this case you're attempting to use PL/SQL.

From what you're attempting to do I assume you're used to SQL Server and temporary tables. It is [less common and less necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192265/local-temporary-table-in-oracle-10-for-the-scope-of-stored-procedure/1193443#1193443) to use temporary tables in Oracle.

Firstly, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE MYTABLE';`. It should rarely be necessary to perform DDL in a stored procedure in Oracle; it would normally be indicative of a flaw in the data-model. In this case it appears as though you're using an actual table as a temporary table. I wouldn't do this. If you need a temporary table use a [global temporary table](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php).

Secondly, `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE`. You can't do this in PL/SQL. If you need to select some data you have to use `SELECT <columns> INTO <variables> FROM ...`. If you do this it won't show you the contents of the table.

From your description of what you're attempting you *only* need to do the following:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM MYOTHERTABLE;
```

There is no need for PL/SQL (stored procedures) at all.

Comment: Hi Ben, I simplified my post by stating that I'm grabbing data from MYOTHERTABLE and inserting it into MYTABLE, in reality I have to join multiple tables and then insert data into MYTABLE. This stored procedure is then going to be used in an RDL report so that's why I was thinking of using SELECT * FROM MYTABLE at the end.

Comment: It doesn't matter @tonto. You're truncating the table first. If the data doesn't need to persist then there's no point using a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you intended to execute the `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE` after the procedure was compiled and executed. The above could be restrucured as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure MYSTOREDPROCEDURE is
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE MYTABLE';

  INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3)
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
      FROM MYOTHERTABLE;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error in MYSTOREDPROCEDURE : ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
END MYSTOREDPROCEDURE;
/

EXECUTE MYSTOREDPROCEDURE
/

SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
/
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

My DBA won't let me have `TRUNCATE` privileges even though truncate removes high water marks compared to `delete MYTABLE;` Your code will fail without these privileges.  Both @Ben and @Bob Jarvis provide sound advice with the missing INTO and nicer form.  One addition to Bob Jarvis' answer is that you need to start the command with `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000;`.  Otherwise, his nicely crafted error message will not be displayed.  The `serveroutput` command is used for `DBMS_OUTPUT` and only lasts as long as your database session lasts.